# How to Split a name and use a function to display a set result

Tags: php, function

Using Php I have to create a function to split a name and then have it display the first character of the first name and all of the last name example is below:

[what it looks like before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaqWH.png)

[what it looks like after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUVp6.png)

the only thing is I have no idea how the only hint i was given was research the PHP strpos() function any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would recommend using explode() function in PHP, with delimiter of space (but you need to perform regex if name, actually, is inserted correctly).
Then, you just use substr() function (for name), get only first character and print it. 
I am not going to write full code for it, because that would destroy point of learning.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the explode() to separate the names like:

```
$names = explode(' ', $fullName);
```

The first letter of the first name:

```
$flfn = substr($names[0], 0,1);
```

Output:

```
echo $flfn . " " . $names[1];
```

You should probably check that the length of the $names array is 2 after the explode so you can manage different cases such as someone with 2 last names.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO.
There can be multiple ways to get this thing.
what I can do for you is as below

```
function getShortName($userId, $connect) {

    $query = $connect->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $query->execute(array([$userId]));
    $user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $names = explode(" ", $user->username);

    $realName = $names[0][0]." ".$names[1];

    echo $realName;
}

$name = "Prateik Darji";

getShortName($name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, i'm really new to php and in the process of learning the names in my table are being pulled from a database and displayed using php. I have successfully created a function for the date the way I want. i am now trying to display the name from my database in the desired format using a function in the code you kindly provided the part that states:

$name = "Prateik Darji"; is there a way to make this so its linked to the information being pulled from my database?

Comment: so are you writing core query for that like you need to contact first name and last name from the database may be as per my understanding right? If yes, can you please update your question with the query?

Comment: so this is my php for displaying the webpage https://ibb.co/NVTWSrJ

i have my function stored as a php documet and li nk back to it in my php code

Comment: you are passing Id of user in this then you have to write query in this function to get user details. I have updated my code